# Looking for good, but quick references for underlying OS concepts related to SQLOS (Memory Access, Scheduling, etc...)?

Tags: sql-server, hardware

Looking for good, but quick references for underlying OS concepts related to SQLOS (Memory Access, Scheduling, etc...)?

I am researching SQLOS and how threads and scheduling are handled, but I would like to review some OS concepts and how SQLOS interacts with the environment. I am aware of the Operating Systems Concepts textbook, but I was wondering if there was a good resource available online that is a little more brief and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad quesiton and will be eventually closed.

Below page from BOL will be helpful to you :

- [**Thread and Task Architecture**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms176043%28v=sql.105%29)
- [Platform layer for SQL Server - A new platform layer in SQL Server 2005 to exploit new hardware capabilities and their trends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/slavao/platform-layer-for-sql-server) by Slava Oks
- [Architectural Overview of SQL Server 2014’s In-Memory OLTP Technology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/)
- [SQL Server Threading Model](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sqlserver-waits) - This is to Paul Randal's online course about wait stats on Pluralsight.